# Yii unserialize and diff

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a problem, probably trivial but I can not deal with it because I snap out of it still gets there any error type: `unserialize (): Error at offset 0 of 31 bytes`

controller:

```
public function actionHistory($id)
{
    $post=Mymodel::model()->findAll('id='.$id);




    if($post == null){
        $error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error;
        if ($error)
            $this->render('error', array('error'=>$error));
        else
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'Page not found.');
    }


    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Mymodel',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'id='.$id,
            'order'=>'id desc',
        )
    ));


    $this->render('history',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'id'=>$id,

    ));
}
```

and my View file:

```
<div class="view" style="float: left; width:100%;">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />
    <div id="old" style="width: 48%; margin: 1%; float: left; ">

        <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('old')); ?>:</b>
        <div id="old" style="float: left; width:100%; background-color:rgba(248, 200, 178, 0.3)">

        <?php

        echo CHtml::encode($data->old);
        ?>
            </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="diff" style="width: 48%; margin: 1%; float: left; ">

        <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('diff')); ?>:</b>
        <div id="diff" style="float: left; width:100%; background-color: rgba(210, 249, 244, 0.45);">

            <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->diff); ?>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, `$data->diff` and `$data->Old` is added to the database for the help serialize, and now needs to use the unserialize to display the data but when it tries to always get an `error unserialize (): Error at offset 0 of 31 bytes or similar.`

Can you help me somehow? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your code here

```
 $post=Mymodel::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"id = $id"));
```

OR you can choose

```
$post=Mymodel::model()->findByPk($id);
```

Do this only if your id is primary key in your database table otherwise go for first one.

Then you will get the correct value.